# How does one extract the definition of a view using standard SQL?

Tags: sql, view, ddl

In trying to answer this question for myself I came across this nugget, after eventually adding "oracle" to my query terms:

```
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','<table_name>') from DUAL;
```

Which works, but is not portable.  How do I do the same thing on MySQL?  SQLite?  Others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since database metadata isn't standardized, there's no standard way to do this.

Comment: That's unfortunate, and I should have realized if there was such a function to handle it in oracle, it's because a standard did not exist.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunate, but not entirely true - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

FOR SQL Server INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS limits the output length to 4000 characters, which to me makes it quite unreliable.

The following works much better with definition as nvarchar(max) and works on multiple object types (VIEW, SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE, SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION, SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION, SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION, possibly more, this is what I see in my DB)

```
SELECT TOP 1000
    O.name
    , O.type
    , O.type_desc
    , M.definition
FROM sys.Sql_modules AS M
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects AS O ON M.object_id=O.object_id
```

Comment: +1 Dude, I wish I could give you a +1000 points for this. I'd give them out of my rep if I could!

Answer (score 2):

Well, there **IS** an ANSI standard called the **INFORMATION_SCHEMA**. Many vendors including Microsoft (SQL Server), Oracle, MySQL, Postgres support it, so that might be a first step.

For more information see this [article here](http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/20561).

As for views, there's three INFORMATION_SCHEMA views for those:

- INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
- INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE
- INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE

There is a column called "VIEW_DEFINITION" in the "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS" view, so that would probably give you the information you need in a somewhat stadandized way.

Marc

Comment: SQLite supports a thing like INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  You, the user, define extra views with names like INFORMATION_SCHEMA_TABLES, which is not precisely the "standard".  This post has a different opinion on the level of support: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/666.cfm